# Next section after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I need to scroll to the next section on the page based on the viewport. when someone 1 scroll the page then land on next section. I have 10 sections to scroll, please help much appreciated

```css
.ttd-banner{
height:600px;
}
```

```html
<section>
                       <div class="fluid-container">
                       <div class="row">
                         <div class="ttd-banner">
                   <img src="images/image-1.jpg">
                    <div class="title">
                              <h4>Heading</h4>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         <div class="container mt-20">
                           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                           </div>
                           
                         </div>
             
             <div class="row">
                         <div class="ttd-banner">
                   <img src="images/image-1.jpg">
                    <div class="title">
                              <h4>Heading</h4>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         <div class="container mt-20">
                           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                           </div>
                           
                         </div>
             
             <div class="row">
                         <div class="ttd-banner">
                   <img src="images/image-1.jpg">
                    <div class="title">
                              <h4>Heading</h4>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         <div class="container mt-20">
                           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                           </div>
                           
                         </div>
             </div>
             </section>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve full page or section scroll?

Comment: thanks for your reply, section scroll, in one scroll one section should comes on viewport

Comment: What happens if a section is too long and overflows the viewport? Is the user unable to scroll to see all of it because the next section is put into the viewport as soon as the user scrolls? Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you trying to achieve.

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var pnls = document.querySelectorAll('.panel').length,
        scdir, hold = false;

    function _scrollY(obj) {
        var slength, plength, pan, step = 100,
            vh = window.innerHeight / 100,
            vmin = Math.min(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth) / 100;
        if ((this !== undefined && this.id === 'container') || (obj !== undefined && obj.id === 'container')) {
            pan = this || obj;
            plength = parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vh);
        }
        if (pan === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        plength = plength || parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vmin);
        slength = parseInt(pan.style.transform.replace('translateY(', ''));
        if (scdir === 'up' && Math.abs(slength) < (plength - plength / pnls)) {
            slength = slength - step;
        } else if (scdir === 'down' && slength < 0) {
            slength = slength + step;
        } else if (scdir === 'top') {
            slength = 0;
        }
        if (hold === false) {
            hold = true;
            pan.style.transform = 'translateY(' + slength + 'vh)';
            setTimeout(function() {
                hold = false;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function _swipe(obj) {
        var swdir,
            sX,
            sY,
            dX,
            dY,
            threshold = 100,
            /*[min distance traveled to be considered swipe]*/
            slack = 50,
            /*[max distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction]*/
            alT = 500,
            /*[max time allowed to travel that distance]*/
            elT, /*[elapsed time]*/
            stT; /*[start time]*/
        obj.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
            swdir = 'none';
            sX = tchs.pageX;
            sY = tchs.pageY;
            stT = new Date().getTime();
        }, false);

        obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        obj.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
            var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
            dX = tchs.pageX - sX;
            dY = tchs.pageY - sY;
            elT = new Date().getTime() - stT;
            if (elT <= alT) {
                if (Math.abs(dX) >= threshold && Math.abs(dY) <= slack) {
                    swdir = (dX < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
                } else if (Math.abs(dY) >= threshold && Math.abs(dX) <= slack) {
                    swdir = (dY < 0) ? 'up' : 'down';
                }
                if (obj.id === 'container') {
                    if (swdir === 'up') {
                        scdir = swdir;
                        _scrollY(obj);
                    } else if (swdir === 'down' && obj.style.transform !== 'translateY(0)') {
                        scdir = swdir;
                        _scrollY(obj);

                    }
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    container.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            scdir = 'down';
        }
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            scdir = 'up';
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    container.addEventListener('wheel', _scrollY);
    _swipe(container);
    
})();
```

```css
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.panel { 
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20px/100vh 'Courier New', monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="panel">
        <p>01</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background:lime;">
        <p>02</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background:orange;">
        <p>03</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background:aqua;">
        <p>04</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background:darkgrey;">
        <p>05</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>06</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you don't want write or use **Javascript** in your build for full page scroll effect, So you can simply use **FullPage.js** javascript library.
[Here is the Youtube tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeZSN6lWsWM)

Comment: Thanks for your help and precious time much appreciated!